# Ffs not returning the right result if its argument is of uint64 type

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

When I try this code, It ouputs 0 instead of the dseried result, which is 35

```
uint64_t er = (uint64_t)1 << 34;
cout << ffs(er);
```

If instead of 34 I use some vale smaller than 32, it works fine, so I assume my compiler isn't using the right ffs, or is it that ffs does not support at all 64 bits types ?

What should I do in this case ? I want to use ffs as I want my code to be the fastest possible, and I heard that ffs has a material implementation.

I am on Ubuntu using g++ and a Xeon processor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [ffs() man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ffs), `ffs()` takes an int parameter.

Try using ffsll() instead:

```
int ffsll(long long int i);
```